# Call a Text Editor on Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, text-files, text-editor

How to call a text editor that can open, save and edit my file that is located on laravel storage folder? Im using Laravel5. Is it possible?

Comment: i think don't matter what you use as a langage, try to use an javascript library like **[Find here some Text Editor Plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-editor-plugins/)**.

Comment: which of these can edit my text file automatically example: text file contains "My name is [user_name]" . In the user_name bracket the user name will be inserted dynamically. Thanks

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i think what you've given links are not my needs. i try ckeditor but it cannot save, edit or open doc file. Any other options

Comment: Ok try this one **[laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/tsawler/laravel-filemanager)**.